# Symfony - Several form on the same page -> ID issue

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I have an issue while displaying several forms of the same model on the same page.
The problem is that with the NameFormat, the fields have the same ID :

```
$this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('display[%s]');
```

Will display

```
<form class="update_display_form" id="update_display_0" action="/iperf/web/frontend_dev.php/update_display" method="post"> 
  <input type="checkbox" name="display[displayed]" checked="checked" id="display_displayed" />
  <label for="display_displayed">test</label> 
</form> 
<form class="update_display_form" id="update_display_1" action="/iperf/web/frontend_dev.php/update_display" method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" name="display[displayed]" checked="checked" id="display_displayed" />
  <label for="display_displayed">truc</label> 
</form>
```

And **if you click on the second label, it will activate the first checkbox**
So I thought I could use the object id to make them unique :

```
$this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('display'.$this->getObject()->getId().'[%s]');
```

But then I can not process the request, since I don't know the name of the parameters.

The best option I found was to set an ID :

```
$this->widgetSchema['displayed']->setAttributes(array("id" => "display".$this->getObject()->getId() ));
```

but then I totally loose the connections between the label and the checkbox.

The problem would be solved if I could change the "for" attribute of my label. Does somebody know how to do that ? Or any other option ?

Comment: I would probably create a new form based on the model and then simply given them different name formats.

Comment: I can not do that, because the number of forms on the page is not fixed. Thanks though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an idea... push a variable to the form class from your action for setting a different name format dynamically:

**In your action:**

```
$this->form_A = new displayForm(array(),array('form_id' = 'A')); // pass a form id
$this->form_B = new displayForm(array(),array('form_id' = 'B'));
$this->form_C = new displayForm(array(),array('form_id' = 'C'));
```

**In your form class:**

```
$form_id = $this->getOption('form_id'); // get the passed value
$this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('display'.$form_id.'[%s]'); // stick it into the name
```

It's ugly but I'm sure you can come up with something cleaner...

Comment: Hmmm that's pretty interesting, thank you. But when I process the form, how do I get the form ID that has been submitted? Currently I use the $request->getParameter('display');  but if the name is dynamically assigned... I could do: 
letter_array = array('A','B',...);
while(!$request->getParameter('display'.letter_array[$i])) {$i++} but this starts to be seriously ugly no ?

Comment: To get the form id that has been submitted, you could either link the 'form_id' variable to the submitted POST request purely in the action, or you could add a hidden input field that submits anything you need it to via the form class.... I think there's some options.

Comment: I hadn't seen your comment, that is the cleanest way I can think about. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Conflicting inter-form checkbox/label interactions is caused by tag's id/for attributes not by their name attributes.

So there is no need to modify form's widget name format and thus having problem reading submitted data from request object (either by passing request key as form url parameter/hidden input or by looping all form name combinations created in the layout for each form and finding a matching one).

sfForm class has sfWidgetFormSchema::setIdFormat() method for that.

```
// Creating form instances

$formA = new sfForm();
$formA->getWidgetSchema()->setIdFormat( '%s1' );
$formA->getWidgetSchema()->setNameFormat( 'display' );
... // configure the form

$formB = new sfForm();
$formB->getWidgetSchema()->setIdFormat( '%s2' );
$formB->getWidgetSchema()->setNameFormat( 'display' );
... // configure the form

$formC = new sfForm();
$formC->getWidgetSchema()->setIdFormat( '%s3' );
$formC->getWidgetSchema()->setNameFormat( 'display' );
... // configure the form


// Processing a request data

$form = new sfForm();
... // configure the form
$_formNameRequestKey = $form->getName();
if( $request->hasParameter( $_formNameRequestKey ) ) {
  $form->bind( $request->getParameter( $_formNameRequestKey ) );
}

... or just ...
if( $request->hasParameter( 'display' ) ) {
  $form->bind( $request->getParameter( 'display' ) );
}
```